# How to calculate area of membrane formed by ring or loop of discrete points?

Tags: numerical-methods, area, 3d

Given a small set of points (ie 6 to 10) with known xyz coordinates, where this set forms a non-planar closed loop or path, is there a way to numerically calculate the area of a membrane formed by this loop?  (ie if this loop were placed in soapy water and then removed, there would be a soap membrane formed that would have a some-what complex 3-D surface, I'm guessing it would be a surface of minimum area or minimum surface tension).  Currently I calculate a sort of "plane of best fit" from the points and then project the points onto the plane and then consider this a 2-D area calculation, but I'm curious if there is a way to look at this area as a 3-D membrane.

Comment: I don't understand how points form a loop... loops are generally continuous curves, whereas points are discrete.  In any event, you seem to be interested in *minimal surfaces* (which gives you something to Google).  My understanding is that describing a minimal surface requires solving a boundary value problem of some sort which, in principle, ought to be doable with numerical techniques.

Comment: Connect the dots.  That's how you go from points to a loop or path.  These points are discrete locations on a particular object being measured.

Comment: I guess there is the possibility of deriving a cubic spline from these points.  I don't know if this makes it easier to calculate the area?